# how to avoid table corruption from long transactions

Tags: database, database-design, firebird

I have two tables stok and stok_detail.Table stock is a summary of table stock_detail.

stok consist of 3 column: item_id, qty and cost

stock detail consist of 5 column: transaction_id, posting_date, item_id, qty and cost.

When someone edit certain transaction,cost might be recalculated.

e.g. Purchasing edit transaction on date 10. all cost on following transactions after date 10 will be recalculated.

I have put all the calculations in stored procedure.

the problem is, this transaction might take hours, if there are many transactions to be recalculated.and there are some occasions that when transaction is running, the power goes down which sometime caused stock_detail table to be corrupted.

**my question is:**

Is it better to put the calculations on temp table first. e.g stock_calc.
and when all the calculations are done, table stock_detail will be updated, taking values from stock_calc. so table stock_detail are updated later after all the calculations are done.

So if something go wrong, I just empty table stock_calc. I know it would be possible that the power goes down when transactions are updating the stock_detail. but probability will be minimized.This will of course take the calculations time longer. but if it is safer, I might consider this approach.

what do you guys think? any comments and ideas will be highly appreciated.

and 1 more thing. if the power goes down, is it possible to see all transactions that are not committed and commit/rollback when I reconnect to the database?

Comment: What version of FB do you use? Latest versions with FORCED WRITES=ON and UPS are quite proof of db corruptions.

Comment: i use fb 2.5. Can you tell me how to use forced writes, or direct me to article about this. thanks

Comment: @Andrej Kirejeŭ   I have checked and forced writes is on

Comment: Ок. What do you mean saying that table becomes corrupted? Is gfix reporting some page level errors?

Comment: yes it does. this is the error: Number of database page errors: 6147

Comment: If so, fill in an issue at http://tracker.firebirdsql.org it will help developers to improve product.

Comment: i will. i'm just gonna check once more to make sure that this is a bug. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firebird is built with [ACID](http://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/papers_presentations/html/paper-fbent-acid.html) compilance in mind. That means "theoretically" even on network or power (except hardware) failure your database should maintain it's integrity.

However there are cases of data corruption, especially on hardware faults or Firebird engine programming bugs. You should upgrade your FB version to latest stable of your major version.

Also, keeping a transaction active for many hours that change a lot of data is not a good architecture design, avoid this.